# Is there a way to subscribe to multiple queues in the NATS Nest.js Microservice?

Tags: nestjs

Currently the `NatsOptions` allows for one `queue` of type `string`.

I have a process that needs to register two queue groups.

Is there a way to use two clients in one microservice?